# Do you have to serve for military service if you get South Korea citizenship?

Tags: south-korea

*Disclaimer: This is not a serious question on me; I just wonder.*

If you are male and get a nationality of South Korea, are you obliged to serve for military service in South Korea?

I have often heard that some Korean boys try hard to get another country's citizenship to avoid the potential military service. But I wonder what is the opposite of the case.

Is it mandatory or exempt? Or does it differ by ages?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Korean_nationality_law), [EasyLaw Korea](http://www.easylaw.go.kr/CSM/SubCnpclsCmd.laf?csmSeq=720&ccfNo=4&cciNo=2&cnpClsNo=6), and [Statutes of the Republic of Korea (in English)](http://elaw.klri.re.kr/eng_service/lawView.do?hseq=32750&lang=ENG):

[Draft-age males](http://elaw.klri.re.kr/eng_service/lawView.do?hseq=32750&lang=ENG) who acquire Korean nationality must [complete or be exempted from military service](http://www.easylaw.go.kr/CSM/SubCnpclsCmd.laf?csmSeq=720&ccfNo=4&cciNo=2&cnpClsNo=6). In Korea, dual nationality is not allowed, so those who acquire [South Korean nationality](http://www.easylaw.go.kr/CSM/SubCnpclsCmd.laf?csmSeq=720&ccfNo=4&cciNo=1&cnpClsNo=1) by naturalization are expected to forfeit their foreign nationality within six months.